# Limit columns on the right table in a LEFTJOIN in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following 2 tables.

```
tb_Posts
--------
PostId, PostName

tb_PostCategories
------------------
PostId, PostCategoryName
```

I want to join both these tables, however, I would like to display all columns and entries in tb_Posts but display PostCategoryName column only from tb_PostCategories even if an entry for tb_Posts.PostId in tb_PostCategories exists or not.

So, I did this query, but it I am getting a SQL error

```
SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT a.PostId, a.PostName from tb_Posts a) y
LEFT JOIN tb_PostCategories z USING (y.PostId)
```

Thanks

Comment: To clarify, do you want all rows from tb_Posts or tb_Postcategories?

Comment: @ron: "I would like to display all columns and entries in tb_Posts"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*` gets all columns.
You can do:

```
SELECT y.*, z.PostCategoryName
  FROM (SELECT a.PostId, a.PostName FROM tb_Posts a) y
       LEFT JOIN tb_PostCategories z 
       ON y.PostId = z.PostId;
```

---

This doesn't really seem to require a subquery, however, so to simplify a bit:

```
SELECT posts.*, cat.PostCategoryName
  FROM tb_Posts posts
       LEFT JOIN tb_PostCategories cat
       ON cat.PostId = posts.PostId;
```

Comment: The first Query with the "USING" keyword didn't work for some reason.. but the second did. :) Thanks a bunch

Comment: @Jake: you're most welcome. Thanks for the comment. The 2nd is really the one you should be using. Nonetheless I edited the first to be more explicit about the join condition.